# type 'undefined' is not assignable to type, losing type in map()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, redux-toolkit

I have an action in my redux toolkit that's attempting to set some state. Relevant code below:

**interfaces**

```
export interface ProposalTag {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  hex: string;
  color: string;
}

export interface ProposalSelectedTag {
  proposal_id: number;
  proposal_tag_id: number;
}
```

**redux**

```
import { ProposalTag, ProposalSelectedTag } from '../../types/proposalTags';

interface ProposalTagsSlice {
  proposalTags: ProposalTag[];
  selectedProposalTags: ProposalTag[];
}

const initialState: ProposalTagsSlice = {
  proposalTags: [],
  selectedProposalTags: [],
};

const matchTags = (
  selectedTags: ProposalSelectedTag[],
  proposalTags: ProposalTag[],
): ProposalTag[] => {
  const tags = selectedTags.map((selectedTag: ProposalSelectedTag) => {
    return proposalTags.find(proposalTag => proposalTag.id === selectedTag.proposal_tag_id);
  });

  return tags ?? [];
};

export const proposalTagsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'proposalTags',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setSelectedProposalTags: (state, action: PayloadAction<ProposalSelectedTag[]>) => {
      if (state.proposalTags === undefined) return;
      state.selectedProposalTags =
        action.payload === null ? [] : matchTags(action.payload, state.proposalTags);
    },
  },
});
```

The goal of `matchTags` is to convert the payload of `ProposalSelectedTag[]` to `ProposalTag[]`.  So in theory, `ProposalSelectedTag.proposal_tag_id`

The type errors I get back are the following:[image]

Did I lose typing somewhere in `matchTags`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `Array.prototype.find` will return `undefined` if the element is not found.

If you are sure that the item exists in the list, you can make an assertion that will calm TypeScript down.

```
const tags = selectedTags.map((selectedTag: ProposalSelectedTag) => {
  const item = proposalTags.find(proposalTag => proposalTag.id === selectedTag.proposal_tag_id);
  if (!item) throw new Error('item was not found')
  return item
});
```

You can also use `!`

```
const tags = selectedTags.map((selectedTag: ProposalSelectedTag) => {
  return proposalTags.find(proposalTag => proposalTag.id === selectedTag.proposal_tag_id)!;
});
```

Or you can set a default value

```
const tags = selectedTags.map((selectedTag: ProposalSelectedTag) => {
  return proposalTags.find(proposalTag => proposalTag.id === selectedTag.proposal_tag_id) ?? 10;
});
```

Comment: Is there anyway to set it to a default value if (!item) or is throwing an error the only way to calm down typescript?